# Angler keeps giving the same quest

Tags: terraria

Every day, the angler gives me the exact same quest. He always wants me to get a Zombie Fish, and I don't know how to get a new quest! Can someone help me?

Comment: Over how many days have you tested this? You might just be having bad luck with the RNG.

Comment: Yea. It fixed itself.

Comment: @MCΔT I am having the same issue now. It has been giving me the dynamite quest 5 times in a row. I guess it's indeed bad luck with the RNG.

Answer (score 2):

On the dawn of every new day, the angler's fishing quest gets reset and you can talk to him to find out which fish you need to catch that day. There are 39 different possible quests available, with about a quarter of those (8) only being available after hardmode is unlocked. Though it's somewhat rare, it's possible that you can get the same quest multiple days in a row. This is coincidence, nothing more.

If these multi-day sprees are annoying to you, there is a way to alleviate the frustration a bit. Once you've caught the quest fish for the day, you will be unable to catch another of the same kind as long as it stays in your inventory. However, if you put that fish into storage and go fishing some more, you can catch more quest fish. Using this method, it's possible to stockpile several of the more tedious quest fish away so you don't have to go fishing again at a later time.

Comment: That's the [problem with randomness](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25), you can never be sure